# is there a profiling gem/plugin for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, profiling

is there a profiling gem/plugin for Ruby on Rails?

That is, where I can then specify the point in a request I want to act as milestones points for a time to be taken, and place them stategically.  Then ideally the plugin then works out and displays how the overall response time was made up...

Tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try [ruby-prof](http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/)? Basically start and stop the profiler around the parts you are interested in, and the profiler breaks it all down for you. Some example output can be found [here](http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/files/examples/graph_txt.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's a new Ruby on Rails [web-server](http://webroar.in/) in the block, which includes a pretty smart profiler inbuilt. You may like it...